# How to produce the plot with shadow in R (gam)?

Tags: r, plot, gam

I have built a gam model with the first graph.

```
library(mgcv)
library(gamair)

a1 <- gam(death~s(time,bs="cr",k=200)+pm10median+so2median+ o3median+tmpd,
data=chicago,family=poisson)
plot(a1)
```

[image: dotted plot]

But how can I produce a plot looked like below?

[image: plot with shadow]

Comment: Please specify the packages used

Comment: see `plot.gam` ; possible `shade` or `scheme` paramteer

Comment: Hi, using `shade` is correct, need to specify in the plot that shade=TRUE.   
plot(a1, shade=TRUE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the comments, and the solution is very simple, `shade` should be used in order to see the shaded plot.

```
library(mgcv)
library(gamair)

a1 <- gam(death~s(time,bs="cr",k=200)+pm10median+so2median+ o3median+tmpd,
data=chicago,family=poisson)
plot(a1, shade=TRUE)
```